# How to increase or decrease textbox value using page object Model

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to input the numeric value in this textbox, I tried using xpath but id is keep on changing everytime,I added the picture and source code below.

[image: How can i input the value in this textbox?]

Here is the source code i managed to select using Xpath but id is keep on changing

```
<input class="t-input" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Amount must be a number." id="CaseTypes_64b4d9c0-c574-40bd-a450-0c6f94844a2e__Amount" name="CaseTypes[64b4d9c0-c574-40bd-a450-0c6f94844a2e].Amount" style="width: 110px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id in your example is

`CaseTypes_64b4d9c0-c574-40bd-a450-0c6f94844a2e__Amount`

I'm guessing the part between `CaseTypes` and `Amount` is random.

You can use the following to select the textbox:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("*[id^='CaseTypes'][id$='Amount']"));
```

`id^=''` means: value should start with
`id$=''` means: value should end with

Combining these two allows you to search for the textbox even when the part between CaseTypes and Amount changes.

After that you can `call.SendKeys("Enter your text here")` to send text to the textbox

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you have shared you can use any of the following options :

- **`XPath`** :

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@class='t-input'][starts-with(@id, 'CaseTypes_')][starts-with(@name, 'CaseTypes[')]")).Click();
  ```
- **`CssSelector`** :

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[class='t-input'][id^='CaseTypes_'][name^='CaseTypes[']")).Click();
  ```